# How to troubleshoot "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: ms-access

I'm creating a ms-access query to filter by month.  I have my list of dates, filter by month using Month(8) as criteria in the field, and am getting a data type mismatch error.  I'm not putting the number in quotation marks and I know the field I'm adding criteria to is in MM/DD/YYYY format because I'm pulling it from a query where I changed it to that format.  I'm sure it's a simple fix but I am VERY new to ms-access.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Read this first, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and adjust your question accordingly. Apart from that, Month(8) won't work, it should be Month(column_name) = 8. And formatting does not convert your data, so you have to format it anytime you want to use it.

Comment: Format property does not change data. Format() function does change data. You need to edit question to show sample data and the query SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm pulling it from a query where I changed it to that format.

That is your trouble. Pull the date field *as is*, not as a formatted string.

Then this **SQL** will work:

```sql
Select * From YourQuery
Where Month([YourDateField]) = 8
```